# Query result with X rows discarded

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In a transaction, if I select results to display to the screen, I get the message `Query result with x rows discarded.`

How can I view those results?  Something is amiss with my query and I want to see what the values are in a temp table at a certain point.

Answer (score 4):

In a transaction (or in an SQL function) only the results from the *last* command are returned to the user. You could write the results to a (temporary) table to inspect them later.

Or you run through your transaction interactively, executing one command after the other.

Comment: +1 - in my view it is typically the `COMMIT;` which makes the previous results discarded.  Another posibility is to define temporary table without `ON COMMIT DROP` - so it is still there after committing and can be queried.